# Why is response undefined in Fetch request using Redux Store

Tags: post, redux, response, fetch

I am writing a Fetch request to post new users to an application. The fetch is integrated with a redux store. Response returns [object Object] and response.status returns undefined. I am new to Redux and am wondering if that is where the error is. Here is the code from my actions creator file:

```
export function createCustomerSuccess(values) {
    return {
        type: types.CREATE_CUSTOMER_SUCCESS,
        values: values
   };
}

export function createCustomer(values) {
   return function (dispatch, getState) {
       console.log('values passing to store', values);
       return postIndividual(values).then( (response) => { 
           console.log('calling customer actions');
           console.log(response);
           if(response.status === 200){
               console.log(response.status);
               dispatch(createCustomerSuccess(values));
               console.log('create customer success');
           }
           else {
               console.log('not successful');
          }
      });
   };
}


function postIndividual(values) {
    console.log('test from post' + JSON.stringify(values));
    const URLPOST = "http://myurlisworking/Add";
    return fetch (URLPOST, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Origin": "*"
       },
       body: JSON.stringify(values)
   })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
      console.log('response' + response.status)
  });   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue seems like with your fetch expectations. When your first `.then` gets called after `fetch()` then you get `response.status` available there to check.

You can rewrite your fetch like below and see if that resolves.

```
function postIndividual(values) {
    console.log('test from post' + JSON.stringify(values));
    const URLPOST = "http://myurlisworking/Add";
    return fetch (URLPOST, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Origin": "*"
       },
       body: JSON.stringify(values)
   })
  .then(response => {
       console.log('response' + response.status)
       return response.ok && response.json();
  })
  .catch(err => console.log('Error:', err));
}
```

You can check `response.status` here ^ and do what you want.

Alternatively you can just do the `fetch` in `postIndividual` and handle response in your `createCustomer` instead.

Comment: Thank you for this response. The fetch does resolve in postIndividual function. I am still getting "undefined" in createCustomer when I try to pass it back ... not sure why. Any additional help much appreciated.

Comment: @Sizzles27 not sure what you mean, code snippet could help me a bit to understand your issue.